# CSS background gradient on tables leaving extra border on some elements on Android 4.0

Tags: android, css, gradient, css-tables

I have a couple of 4 column tables where I'm adding a background gradient via CSS -

```
tr, td {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #335781), color-stop(100%, #00244e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #335781 0%, #00244e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #335781 0%, #00244e 100%); /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #335781 0%, #00244e 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

This works great in Chrome & Firefox and provides a linear gradient for the entire table row.  However, when viewed on an Android 4.0 device in the stock browser, I'm ending up with what looks like a solid color border between each of the  tags.  I've done all of the usual things to make sure there are no borders: `cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0` on the table tag, as well as `border-collapse: collapse, border-spacing: 0`, and `border: 0` in the stylesheet on table.  Just for fun, I also tried -webkit-border-image and set that to the same gradient.

I'm frustrated at this point.  Any other idea how to be rid of this additional border/spacing?

Comment: Noticed the same behavior too, probably a valid stock browser bug. This may not be the solution but if you're table has 1 or few rows, try moving the gradient into `table`

Comment: My initial testing was on a Samsung Galaxy Reverb with Android 4.0.  I've now done some additional testing on a Galaxy III with Android 4.1 and see that there is no problem there.  So the issue is either with 4.0 or with my device.